# UIWebView user interaction (click) delay

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, onclick, delay

whenever I make a tap action on a UIWebView, for example clicking a link, there is a slightly delay between the tap and the actual highlighting / activating of the link.

Is there a way to disable this delay?

I've read that this would be possible in UIScrollView with

```
setDelaysContentTouches:NO
```

Is this also possible in UIWebViews?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution I used:

http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone

Answer (score 5):

In iOS5 the UIScrollView belonging to a UIWebView has been exposed so that you can change its behavior. So to remove the click delays you can simply do:

```
[webView.scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO]
```

As a bonus, you can make the scrolling in a UIWebView feel a bit more native by changing the decelerationRate:

```
[webView.scrollView setDecelerationRate:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal]
```

Comment: Unfortunately setDelaysContentTouches is the touchdown delay, whereas the click delay is caused by waiting for doubletap. This solution doesn't appear to fix that.